# Gnosis Safe workers not works in local environment

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I run Gnosis Safe in local environment; I encounter this error

```
2023-11-29 11:28:45 2023-11-29 03:28:45,601 [ERROR] [???/???] pidbox command error: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'")
2023-11-29 11:28:45 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-11-29 11:28:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 102, in dispatch
2023-11-29 11:28:45     reply = handle(method, arguments)
2023-11-29 11:28:45             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-29 11:28:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 124, in handle_cast
2023-11-29 11:28:45     return self.handle(method, arguments)
2023-11-29 11:28:45            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-29 11:28:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 118, in handle
2023-11-29 11:28:45     return self.handlers[method](self.state, **arguments)
2023-11-29 11:28:45            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-29 11:28:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/control.py", line 340, in enable_events
2023-11-29 11:28:45     if dispatcher.groups and 'task' not in dispatcher.groups:
2023-11-29 11:28:45        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-11-29 11:28:45 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please specify the repo you are trying to run and the steps you followed until the error was thrown?
Context is missing in this question.